# Jquery Works only once for alert of Bootstrap I am showing on page Asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want it to work every time. Every time I click on the save button without refreshing the page.

Here is my code.

**Jquery Code In Admin.Master:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#successalert").hide();
    $("#sucess").click(function showAlert() {
        $("#successalert").alert();
        $("#successalert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
            $("#successalert").alert('close');
        });
    });
});
```

**Settings.aspx Code**

```
<div class="modal" id="menuiconmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Menu</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">                
       // some input tags    
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">

            <a href="javascript:;" id="sucess" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>  
    <!-- /.modal -->

    // Alert Showing for a while 

    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="successalert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Hey!</h4> Menu Item Added Sucessfully !!!!
    </div>
```

Comment: are you using update panel?

Comment: No I am not using <asp:Updatepanel>.

Comment: what you are doing is you are hiding  `$("#successalert").hide();` on initial click event  , but for second click event you will not able to see it

Comment: At the **Initial stage** i want to hide that alert  by using `$("#successalert").hide();`

Comment: Are you trying to alert or modal?

Comment: I am tring for alert showing on Modal's button. In the modal I have Button with id="sucess". while clicking on that button form validation will be fired and then **Success Alert** will be shown .

Comment: @NatavarGhodasara after first click event try to get the successalert to show.

Comment: never use hide or show when working with bootstrap plugins. [try these methods](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts-methods)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Bootstrap itself as detailed in this [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/10752).

There are some workarounds mentioned [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/1845) which you can try.

Answer (score 0):

**Found Solution with Jquery addClass() and removeClass()**

**CSS**
**Changed .alert class in bootstrap.css with below property**

```
display:none;
```

**Added new class for showing**

```
.showing
    {
        display:inherit;            
        padding: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
```

**jquery Code**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sucess").click(function () {         
        $("#successalert").removeClass("alert");           
        $("#successalert").addClass("showing");           
        $("#successalert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
            $("#successalert").alert('close');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```